# Python numpy nonzero cumsum

Tags: python, numpy

I want to do nonzero `cumsum` with `numpy` array. Simply skip zeros in array and apply `cumsum`. Suppose I have a np. array

```
a = np.array([1,2,1,2,5,0,9,6,0,2,3,0])
```

my result should be

```
[1,3,4,6,11,0,20,26,0,28,31,0]
```

I have tried this

```
a = np.cumsum(a[a!=0])
```

but result is

```
[1,3,4,6,11,20,26,28,31]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How about `b=np.cumsum(a)` and then `b[a==0]=0`?

Comment: @jotasi - good suggestion. You should make it an answer.

Comment: @mtrw Thanks, but I guess that two liner does not really justify an answer, especially since EdChum's answer seems more elegant to me anyway.

Comment: @jotasi - Your's is faster than Ed Chum's. See some timings I posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just trying to simplify it:)

```
b=np.cumsum(a)
[b[i]  if ((i > 0 and b[i] != b[i-1]) or i==0) else 0 for i in range(len(b))]
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to mask the original array so only the non-zero elements are overwritten:

```
In [9]:
a = np.array([1,2,1,2,5,0,9,6,0,2,3,0])
a[a!=0] = np.cumsum(a[a!=0])
a

Out[9]:
array([ 1,  3,  4,  6, 11,  0, 20, 26,  0, 28, 31,  0])
```

Another method is to use `np.where`:

```
In [93]:
a = np.array([1,2,1,2,5,0,9,6,0,2,3,0])
a = np.where(a!=0,np.cumsum(a),a)
a

Out[93]:
array([ 1,  3,  4,  6, 11,  0, 20, 26,  0, 28, 31,  0])
```

**timings**

```
In [91]:
%%timeit
a = np.array([1,2,1,2,5,0,9,6,0,2,3,0])
a[a!=0] = np.cumsum(a[a!=0])
a

The slowest run took 4.93 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.6 µs per loop

In [94]:    
%%timeit
a = np.array([1,2,1,2,5,0,9,6,0,2,3,0])
a = np.where(a!=0,np.cumsum(a),a)
a

The slowest run took 6.00 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.5 µs per loop
```

the above shows that `np.where` is marginally quicker than the first method

Answer (score 1):

To my mind, jotasi's suggestion in a comment to the OP is the most idiomatic. Here are some timings, though note that Shawn. L's answer returns a Python list, not a NumPy array, so they are not strictly comparable.

```
import numpy as np

def jotasi(a):
  b = np.cumsum(a)
  b[a==0] = 0
  return b

def EdChum(a):
  a[a!=0] = np.cumsum(a[a!=0])
  return a

def ShawnL(a):
  b=np.cumsum(a)
  b = [b[i]  if ((i > 0 and b[i] != b[i-1]) or i==0) else 0 for i in range(len(b))]
  return b

def Ed2(a):
  return np.where(a!=0,np.cumsum(a),a)
```

To test, I generated a NumPy array of 1E5 integers in [0,100]. Therefore about 1% are 0. These results are from NumPy 1.9.2, Python 2.7.12, and are presented from slowest to fastest:

```
import timeit
a = np.random.random_integers(0,100,100000)

len(a[a==0]) #verify there are some 0's
1003

timeit.timeit("ShawnL(a)", "from __main__ import a,EdChum,ShawnL,jotasi,Ed2", number=250)
11.743098020553589
timeit.timeit("EdChum(a)", "from __main__ import a,EdChum,ShawnL,jotasi,Ed2", number=250)
0.1794271469116211
timeit.timeit("Ed2(a)", "from __main__ import a,EdChum,ShawnL,jotasi,Ed2", number=250)
0.1282949447631836
timeit.timeit("jotasi(a)", "from __main__ import a,EdChum,ShawnL,jotasi,Ed2", number=250)
0.09286999702453613
```

I'm a little surprised there's such a big difference between jotasi's and Ed Chum's answers - minimizing boolean operations is noticeable I guess. No surprise that a list comprehension is slow.

Comment: The array sizes here are tiny so this isn't that comparative, you should time using large arrays to get a better idea of the efficiency

Comment: @EdChum I agree. Nice summary nontheless. Especially, since I just checked with a large (1000000 elements) random array and the difference actually grew. This is kind of surprising to me as I actually thought your solution was not just nicer but expected it to be faster, as well.

Comment: I find it slightly depressing or impressed that list comprehension performs as well or better than np methods, it's unclear to me why this should be case though. Also why is this a community wiki answer?

Comment: @EdChum - the list comprehension is by far the slowest of the three methods. I made it community wiki because I'm not contributing a new answer, just a way to compare.

Comment: Ah right, I thought your `timeit` code was in the same order as the method declarations which is why I thought list comprehension was quickest

Comment: actually can you try timing `a = np.where(a!=0,np.cumsum(a),a)` this seems faster compared to my original answer